# prometheus promql to fetch pods within certain time

Tags: prometheus, promql

Team, i have a query to pull certain expression matched pods and namespaces but i want to pull them for last x number of days. how to ?

```
count(kube_pod_info{namespace=~"team-.*", pod=~"export-.*"} ) by (namespace)
```

output

**Element**---------------------------------------------                                               **Value**

```
{namespace="team-a4-db8a1b8b054f"}  500
```

attempted query to get same result for last 1d: see in end of query `[1d]`

```
count(kube_pod_info{namespace=~"team-.*", pod=~"export-.*"} ) by (namespace)[1d]
```

error output

```
Error executing query: invalid parameter 'query': 1:195: parse error: ranges only allowed for vector selectors
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
count by (namespace) (
  max_over_time(kube_pod_info{namespace=~"team-.*", pod=~"export-.*"}[1d])
)
```